# Possible to create a class method chain with sub chains?

Tags: php

Let's say I have a class that builds fields, and I want to do something like this:

```
$section = new Group('services');
$section
  ->addRepeater('showcase')
    ->setMinRows(3)
    ->addField('text')
    ->addField('image')
  ->endRepeater()
  ->endGroup();
```

I know with method chaining you can return the parent instance using `$this`, but I'm not sure if it's possible to chain sub classes.

For example, if `addRepeater` returned a Repeater class instance, I could run methods on that, but then how to I take the data it returns and store it in the parent `Group` class?

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if addRepeater returned a Repeater class instance, I could run 
>   methods on that, but then how to I take the data it returns and store it in the parent Group class?

You cannot. You either return `A` or `B` so you cannot mix chains directly. By logic, `addRepeater()` should not return `Repeater` but `Group` and if `addField()` is method of `Repeater` then you need to chain it outside:

```
$repeater = (new Repeater('showcase'))
    ->setMinRows(3)
    ->addField('text')
    ->addField('image')
    ->endRepeater();

$section = new Group('services');
$section
  ->addRepeater($repeater)
  ->endGroup();
```

or make `Repeater` related methods require repeater object (constructed outside the chain it is used in) as argument, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by passing the Group object to the repeater. All you need to remember is that the objects are always passed by reference, so any changes you do in a child class will be available in the parent as well.

```
class Repeater
{
    private $name;
    private $group;
    private $fields = [];

    public function __construct($name, Group $group)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->group = $group;
    }

    public function addField($field)
    {
        $this->fields[] = $field;

        return $this;
    }

    public function endRepeater()
    {
        return $this->group;
    }
}

class Group
{
    private $name;
    private $repeaters = [];

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function addRepeater($name)
    {
        $repeater = new Repeater($name, $this);

        $this->repeaters[] = $repeater;

        return $repeater;
    }

    public function endGroup()
    {
        echo 'group ended';
    }
}

$section = new Group('services');
$section
  ->addRepeater('showcase')
    ->addField('test')
    ->addField('test 1')
  ->endRepeater()
  ->addRepeater('another repeater')
    ->addField('something')
    ->addField('something else')
  ->endRepeater()
  ->endGroup();

var_dump($section);
```

The result would be something like

```
object(Group)#1 (2) {
  ["name":"Group":private]=>
  string(8) "services"
  ["repeaters":"Group":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Repeater)#2 (3) {
      ["name":"Repeater":private]=>
      string(8) "showcase"
      ["group":"Repeater":private]=>
      *RECURSION*
      ["fields":"Repeater":private]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "test"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "test 1"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Repeater)#3 (3) {
      ["name":"Repeater":private]=>
      string(16) "another repeater"
      ["group":"Repeater":private]=>
      *RECURSION*
      ["fields":"Repeater":private]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(9) "something"
        [1]=>
        string(14) "something else"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that! Thanks for the tip, I'm going to play around with it.